# Trouble with horizontally aligning text inside a division using <div> <a> <p>

Tags: html, css

I don't know why i'm having this trouble. Please have a look at the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

My css looks like this:

```
#tabbase {
   display : inline-block;
   width : 230px;
   height : 173px;
   border : 1px solid #3e3e3e;
   background-color : #1b1b1b;
   box-shadow : 0px 0px 4px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) inset;
   margin-top : 6px;
}

#tabbase a {
   display : block;
   height : 43px;
   text-decoration : none;
   font-family : 'Nexa Bold';
   font-size : 24px;
}

#tabbase a p {
   text-align : center;
}
```

And heres the html:

```
<div id = "tabbase">
   <a id = "blog" href = "#"> <p> Blog </p> </a>
   <a class = "batl" href = "#"> <p> Home </p> </a>
   <a class = "batl" href = "#"> <p> Contact </p> </a>
   <a class = "batl" href = "#"> <p> Samples </p> </a>
</div>
```

I don't know why this is so difficult in css, everything else is easy. Iv'e tried margin, padding, border, vertical-align and now text-align.

Why isn't it working?

p.s: if it will help, the background image for the `<a id = "blog">` tag is this css:

```
#tabbase #blog {
   color : #000000;
   background-image : url('Tab.png');
}
```

When I use span I get this:

[image: screenshot 2]

When I add `text-align:center;` to the anchor tag I get this:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/107533178/Screen%20shot%202012-10-21%20at%202.18.38%20PM.png

Comment: why doesn't my image show? I uploaded it? Sorry guys Let me upload through my ftp.

Comment: why are you using p tags? use a span. you don't even need the p tag or a span or anything

Comment: gotta stop putting spaces between all your HTML tags and =.... that's not how HTML is written. It's going to cause headaches if you put spaces between all your HTML tags

Comment: add `text-align: center` to the `a` tag. you don't need an inner tag for that

Comment: Alright let me try that.

Comment: So you want them to be vertically aligned better?

Comment: Cory it worked! L-I-N-E H-E-I-G-H-T Ha! Who would've guessed! Thank you a thousand times cory! +1 for being so active and helpful, have a cheers and a great day, from Mithos! :D

Comment: no problem. CSS is pretty bizarre

Comment: it really is :) Cheers for the great help mate!

Comment: @CoryDanielson You should consider posting that as an answer, so the OP can accept that (makes it easier for future visitors to see the solution to this problem).

Comment: I agree with Jeroen, Cory, it would be my pleasure to mark it correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this style:

```
#tabbase *
{
  text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

It sets all children of DIV#tabbase to be centered both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Hi Mathew, Is the * doing something? Maybe its a typo? I actually tried this method (found it on w3schools), I'm not sure why it didn't work.

Comment: The '*' is a wildcard. Meaning it matches all tags.

Comment: ahh I see, Thank you ^^ it does work! +1 mate I'll mark this one right since cory doesn't want to post an answer. Cheers for the great help! Have a wonderful evening! :)